# Pulled files are excluded from the project in VS2019

Tags: git, visual-studio-2019

Unfortunately I do not have any specific steps to reproduce the issue, but here is what happens:

1. I make changes to a branch, adding files/folders to the project and writing code inside
2. I add the files to a commit, then i push the changes to the branch
3. Someone else pulls the changes made to the branch we're working on, and the files are being brought, but not included in the project.

[Here's a link to the same issue, encountered by someone else:](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/pulled-changes-files-are-automatically-excluding-f/1232329)

Comment: Is the project file added to the commit? Or is it maybe listed in `.gitignore` by accident?

Comment: If Git is transferring the commits properly, and the commits have the correct files in them, this has nothing to do with Git. I think you'll find the answer if you sit down and define what it means for a file to be "included in the project": that probably means "listed within some particular file". You'll need to include that file as a committed file *or* generate / update that file after updating commits. If the file is XML, be aware that Git cannot merge XML correctly, so regenerating the file is probably a better idea.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: what i mean by "included in the project" is that the file is directly visible from the visual studio file explorer, and is added to the .csproj file of the project

Comment: Upgrading your projects to the new project style will auto-include them, since the project file won't list all of the files anymore, but uses clever wildcards. https://natemcmaster.com/blog/2017/03/09/vs2015-to-vs2017-upgrade/